# when running code to display images on screen my game window freezes temporarily

Tags: python, pygame

In a game I am making, the user can take part in arena battles. Upon winning an arena they are meant to be congratulated via text on-screen and, depending on if they've cleared the arena before or not, get given a trophy or get told how many times they've won.

The code outlining what happens if the players' won before and if the player has only won for the first time is virtually similar, but the game freezes when it reaches the part of my `if`/`elif` statement outlining the conditions for if the player's already beaten the arena once.

Code for context [text is a separate file used for writing text to my screen, using booleans to determine if it's bold, it's position, etc]:

```
import pygame, time, text

if battleWon == True and x == len(enemyList)-1: #if the user won the fight and they were on the last enemy
    screen.fill(bg_colour) #code for clearing screen
    screen.blit(prevwindow,(150,100)) #drawing menus
    text.textDisplay("arena champion!",300,140,True,14,"center",screen) #informing they've won
    timesCompleted += 1 #incrementing their win count
    pygame.display.update() #updating diaplay
    time.sleep(2) #keeping message on screen

    if arenaComplete == False: #if they havent beaten the arena before
        arenaComplete = True #set to true
        screen.fill(bg_colour)
        screen.blit(prevwindow,(150,100))
        text.textDisplay("you got a trophy!",300,140,False,14,"center",screen)# tell them they got a trophy
        screen.blit(trophy, (250,160)) #show image of trophy
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(2)

    elif arenaComplete == True: #if already beaten
        screen.fill(bg_colour)
        screen.blit(prevwindow,(150,100))
        text.textDisplay("you've now won "+str(timesCompleted)+" times!",300,140,False,14,"center",screen) #show how many times they've beaten arena
        screen.blit(trophy, (250,160)) #trophy...
        text.textDisplay("x" + str(timesCompleted),375,160,False,14,"topleft",screen) # ... x(no. of times won)
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(2)

elif battleWon == False: #if player loses
    print(":(") #placeholder
```

I've read over the code many times and I can't see why this is happening. There doesn't seem to be any errors in the syntax as it would've shown up in the shell. If the code was for some reason skipping out the `elif arenaComplete == True` part it would simply jump back to my game's main loop without freezing.

EDIT: due to some confusion in the comments I'll clarify that the time.sleep code, as far as I'm aware, does not cause the problem I'm describing. I want the message to be displayed on the screen for the given amount of time, the problem being that the code under the `"elif arenaComplete == True"` statement isn't making anything display at all. Here's what I said in a comment if it explains better:

> What I mean is that the code under the "elif arenaComplete == True"
>   screen doesn't actually blit anything to the screen, despite the
>   "pygame.display.update" which comes BEFORE the time.sleep code,
>   meaning something must be happening beforehand but I am not sure what.
>   The code in the previous "if arenaComplete == False" section is almost
>   identical and for this reason I cannot think of any reason as to why
>   this is happening.

Comment: Your game should freeze twice for at least 2 seconds after a won battle, because of the `time.sleep(2)` statements. Is that the problem?

Comment: `time.sleep(2)` freezes for 2 seconds. Does it freeze differently? What exactly do you expect?

Comment: @ThomasWeller and @rincewind I am aware that the game freezes for the two seconds due to the sleep calling, I think my wording wasn't the best in explaining. What I mean is that the code under the `"elif arenaComplete == True"` screen doesn't actually blit anything to the screen, despite the `"pygame.display.update"` which comes BEFORE the time.sleep code, meaning something must be happening beforehand but I am not sure what. The code in the previous `"if arenaComplete == False"` section is almost identical and for this reason I cannot think of any reason as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

As commentators have pointed out, the game is locking up during the `time.sleep(2)` calls.

Really in any sort of event-driven program, it's not ideal to lock the whole process with a sleep-cycle.  Especially in the loop that handles the events, as this can have other screen-paint consequences.

So how do you code around this?  With a [State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

The game outlined above seems to have three states: "battle", "results" and "gameover" (presumably).  Depending on what *state* the game is in, the display is different, and the user-input is handled differently.

First, lets define some states for the game, using a python [Enumerated Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type).

```
import enum

class GameState( enum.Enum ):
    BATTLE    = 1
    WONGAME   = 2
    GAMEOVER  = 3
    STARTMENU = 4
```

This allows us to reference the current state with a human-readable name:

```
game_state = GameState.BATTLE

 ...

if ( game_state == GameState.GAMEOVER ): 
    ...
```

It's not strictly necessary to use an enumerated type for this, just a string-description would suffice.  But using an enumerated type is generally how this sort of thing is handled in a state machine (and is normal for software generally). As a bonus it catches typos with compile errors.

Anyway, so during the window drawing and event processing, the code checks the current game state to see how to paint the screen:

```
### Main Loop
# Re-draw the screen
if ( game_state == GameState.STARTMENU ):
    WINDOW.fill( NAVY_BLUE )
    drawMenu( start_menu )
elif ( game_state == GameState.BATTLE ):
    SPRITES.update()
    WINDOW.fill( INKY_BLACK )
    SPRITES.draw( WINDOW )
    ...
elif ( game_state == GameState.GAMEOVER ):
    WINDOW.fill( INKY_BLACK )
    # tell user they failed
    ...
elif ( game_state == GameState.WONGAME ):
    WINDOW.fill( bg_colour )               #code for clearing screen
    WINDOW.blit( prevwindow, ( 150,100 ) ) #drawing menus
    #informing they've won
    text.textDisplay( "arena champion!", 300, 140, True, 14, "center", WINDOW )
    if ( arenaComplete == False ): 
        ...

# Update the window, but not more than 60fps
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )
```

Similarly in the event handling, for say a keypress, sometimes a different thing needs to happen depending on the state.  For example if we're in `GameState.STARTMENU` pressing arrow keys might change the menu highlight-selection, but in `GateState.BATTLE` they move the player.  It gets a bit involved, but it's not difficult.  It also has the side-effect of enforcing a rigid simplicity on the handling, making for tidier source-code.

```
# Handle user input
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
        done = True
    elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if ( game_state == GameState.SOMEMENU ):
            # Up/Down changes selecton
            if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
                my_menu.selectPrevious()
            elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
                my_menu.selectNext()
            elif ( keys[pygame.K_ENTER] ):
                # Do item from menu
                ...

        elif ( game_state == GameState.GAMEOVER ):
            # any key-press go back to main menu
            game_state = GameState.STARTMENU

        elif ( game_state == GameState.BATTLE ):
            if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
                player_sprite.moveUp()
            elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
                player_sprite.moveDown()
            ...
```

This state machine method allows for the program screen-context to switch easily.  It means there's no need for `time.sleep()` delays to show something to the user.  It can stay at the "won" screen until a key is pressed.

Here I present a simple example, where pressing any key cycles through the three states.  Each state shows a different screen.  Alas, I do not currently have time for implementing a state-driven key-press handler too.

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import enum

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
# background colours
NAVY_BLUE     = ( 28,  20, 186)
INKY_BLACK    = (  0,   0,   0)
CRIMSON       = (195,  11,  41) 
BAD_SNOW      = (255, 252, 216)

class GameState( enum.Enum ):
    MOVING   = 1
    MENU     = 2
    GAMEOVER = 3


class MovingSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A bouncing Eyeball, just because """
    def __init__( self ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        self.image       = pygame.image.load("eyeball_32.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.newPosition()

    def newPosition( self ):
        # Position to somewhere random
        self.rect.center = ( random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH ), random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

    def update( self ):
        self.newPosition()

### MAIN
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )
pygame.display.set_caption("State Machine Example")


# Add some sprites
MOVERS = pygame.sprite.Group()   # a group, for a single sprite
for i in range(3):
    MOVERS.add( MovingSprite() )

# Font for menus (and whatever)
text_font = pygame.font.Font( None, 60 )  # just a default font

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done  = False
game_state = GameState.MOVING
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )
        elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN ):
            # Move to next state on any keypress, with loop
            if ( game_state == GameState.MOVING ):
                game_state = GameState.MENU
            elif ( game_state == GameState.MENU ):
                game_state = GameState.GAMEOVER
            elif ( game_state == GameState.GAMEOVER ):
                game_state = GameState.MOVING 

    # Repaint the screen, depending on the state
    if ( game_state == GameState.MOVING ):
        MOVERS.update() # re-position the flower-pot
        WINDOW.fill( INKY_BLACK )
        MOVERS.draw( WINDOW )    # draw the flower-pot

    elif ( game_state == GameState.MENU ):
        WINDOW.fill( NAVY_BLUE )
        menu_items   = [ "1. Something", "2. Something Else", "3. Third Choice" ]
        total_height = 0  # use to tally menu height (for centering)
        max_width    = 0
        # Make the menu images, work out the size it needs
        for i in range( len( menu_items ) ):
            # convert text into image, in-place
            menu_items[i] = text_font.render( menu_items[i], True, BAD_SNOW )
            max_width     = max( max_width, menu_items[i].get_width() )
            total_height  = total_height + menu_items[i].get_height()
        # Now draw to screen
        cursor_x = ( WINDOW_WIDTH - max_width ) // 2      # centred on largest menu item
        cursor_y = ( WINDOW_HEIGHT - total_height ) // 2
        for i in range( len( menu_items ) ):
            WINDOW.blit( menu_items[i], ( cursor_x, cursor_y ) )
            cursor_y += 5 + menu_items[i].get_height()  # move down height, plus a bit

    elif ( game_state == GameState.GAMEOVER ):
        WINDOW.fill( CRIMSON )
        # Write "Game Over" text to middle of screen (image could be pre-generated)
        game_over_text = text_font.render( "* Game Over *", True, BAD_SNOW )
        centred_x      = ( WINDOW_WIDTH  - game_over_text.get_width()  ) // 2
        centred_y      = ( WINDOW_HEIGHT - game_over_text.get_height() ) // 2
        WINDOW.blit( game_over_text, ( centred_x, centred_y ) )

    pygame.display.flip()
    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )

pygame.quit()
```

[image: eyeball_32.png]  `eyeball_32.png`